# Automatic content slider for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, telerik, windows-phone, slideshow

I'm wondering what would be the easiest way to display some text inside a Windows Phone (7) app that autimatically changes every few seconds. Is there a ready-to-use control out there that I can simply bind a list of strings to and that is also listening to user input for manually switching content?

I thought about using the Telerik SlideView control, however I can't tell if this supports automatically switching content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Telerik SlideView control](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radslideview-overview.html) doesn't directly support a slideshow mode but it's very easy to add one...

(the following code is taken from the Telerik Examples app)

```
private DispatcherTimer playTimer;

public FirstLook()
{
    this.playTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    this.playTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    this.playTimer.Tick += this.OnPlayTimerTick;
}

private void OnPlayTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.slideView.MoveToNextItem();
}

private void OnPlayTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.playTimer.IsEnabled)
    {
        this.StopSlideShow();
    }
    else
    {
        this.playTimer.Start();
        this.buttonImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/pause.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
}

private void StopSlideShow()
{
    this.playTimer.Stop();
    this.buttonImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/play.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

[The demo app is available on the Windows Phone Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/telerik-examples/fd55f526-d6f7-df11-9264-00237de2db9e), which shows this in motion.